# Why cannot we call prototype functions?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

Initially I assigned function object to variable Person. At this moment, Person's **proto** is pointing to Function.prototype. Then I added some functions to Person.prototype. When I call Person constructor with new keyword below and assign it to var test, as far as I know, it sets test **proto** to Person.prototype. This Person.prototype is an object, with getName mapped to a function. So when I call test.getName(), it searches for the function in test.prototype and if it doesn't find it there, then it will search for the function in its **proto** i.e. Person.prototype.

Now suppose I create another function object and assign it to variable Customer. It's **proto** would be pointing to Function.prototype. Then for inheritance we should do Customer.prototype = new Person(). I am confused about why I should do this? Does it sets Customer's **proto** to Person.prototype. If it does , then shouldn't I just write Customer = new Person(). If it doesn't than, do Customer **proto** still points to Function.prototype or is there something else that I am missing ?

```
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    console.log("Running the constructor of Person " + name)
}

Person.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
}

var test = new Person("Yolo");
console.log(Person.prototype.getName.call(test))
console.log(test.getName());

var Customer = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    console.log("Running the constructor of Customer " + name)
};

Customer.prototype = new Person();
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hint: What's the difference between `var test = new Person()` and `var Test.prototype = new Person()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different concepts here:

- `__proto__` is the object's parent in the inheritance tree.
- `prototype` is a function's property which defines what the `__proto__` will be of any objects it creates when used as a constructor.

Since constructors are objects themselves (function objects), they also are in an inheritance tree, but that tree has nothing to do with the inheritance tree of the objects created by these constructors. They are two separate worlds.

Look at this code, which illustrates the inheritance chain for a customer object:

```
var cust = new Customer('Jack');
console.log(cust.__proto__ === Customer.prototype); // true
console.log(cust.__proto__.__proto__ === Person.prototype); // true
console.log(cust.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype); // true
```

So here we followed the prototype chain of the `cust` object. This is an entirely different chain from the chains for the constructors (functions):

```
console.log(Customer.__proto__ === Function.prototype); // true
console.log(Person.__proto__ === Function.prototype); // true
console.log(Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype); // true
```

Nothing unusual here: they are functions. Also, it is not necessary to change anything to that. As said, it does not relate to the inheritance for the objects these constructors create.

Note that you should never need to access the `__proto__` property. The above is only provided for illustrating the inheritance chain.

Comment: Finally the enlightenment moment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
Customer.___proto____ = Function.prototype
```

It will always be pointing to the Function prototype

```
Customer.prototype = new Person();
```

This statement will make Customer.prototype._____proto_____ point towards Person.Prototype

Customer._____proto_____ will never change only its prototype 's ____proto___ changes by inheritance

Comment: This is an implementation detail that's not part of the javascript standard. Always use `.prototype`

Comment: This is how inheritance works .I am just explaining how proto links are setup.Obviously these proto links are not used in code

Comment: But then when I do like this, var test2 = new Customer(); and call test2.getName(), then it will search for the function in test2.prototype, then test2 __proto__ prototype, i.e. Customer.prototype, it wouldn't find it there, so it will search it in Customer's __proto__ i.e. Function.prototype. So, this way it never reaches real function.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found this image useful. It shows all the links clearly.